# Get the total count of all files submitted in Fine Uploader

Tags: count, fine-uploader, onsubmit

FineUploader fires submit event event after each file is selected, and you can run a counter in that event.

However, I need to know when all files were submitted to start the upload process. There is an "allComplete" event. Is there an equivalent for when all files were submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like using getUploads without any filter works. fineUploader("getUploads")